# Should a Slicer/Timeline selection affect all related pivot tables?

Tags: powerpivot

I have a simple PowerPivot model with 2 tables:

DimDate & UserTransactions

I have defined a relationship on [Date] between the two tables.

Now, if I create multiple pivot charts in Excel based on both DimDate and UserTransactions (Axis comes from DimDate, Values come from UserTransaction), and then I decide that I want to use a slicer or a timeline tied to DimDate, should I or should I not expect that selecting an item in the slicer/timeline will filter the pivot charts?

The behavior I am seeing is no, it does not by default act upon all pivot charts - to do so, you must right click the slicer, choose "Report Connections", and then place a checkmark on each Pivot Chart that you want associated with the slicer, and they all then react to the slicer selection.  This implies that the slicer is acting upon the pivot chart, and not the PowerPivot model itself.

This isn't unreasonable, and in cases could be beneficial (if you *don't* want all pivots tied to one slicer).

However, on the other hand, this seems a bit dangerous in that it could be extremely easy in a large model to miss associating a slicer with all pivots.  Also, it seems inconsistent with the following blog post, which implies that the slicer filtering *is acting upon the PowerPivot model itself, rather than individual pivot tables.

http://tinylizard.com/power-pivot-relationships/

> But the most important understanding is that any filters applied to a
>   lookup table are also applied to related data tables.  And, the
>   reverse is not true.  That is where the direction really matters.
>
> It does not matter why this filter is happening.  If I have a
>   relationship between my Calendar table and Sales[SalesDate], it does
>   not matter “how” a filter got applied to the Calendar table so that
>   Calendar[Year]=2009… the impact is that the filter will also be
>   applied to the data table (Sales).  It could be from a slicer.  It
>   could be because you put Year on rows.  It could be because you wrote
>   a CALCULATE().  Anything.   But, the reverse is not true.  A filter on
>   your Sales table has no impact on your Calendar table.   Relationships
>   have direction.

**So:** 
Is the behavior (that slicers are tied to individual pivot tables, and not tied to the powerpivot model) I am observing the correct (and *only*) behavior available?  You *cannot* apply filtering at the model level, and therefore what is implied in that blog post is technically incorrect?

Or is there possibly an alternate approach that *does* support filtering at the model level?

Comment: You are observing the only behavior, where a slicer filters a pivot table. Picky tables execute wireless against the model, as do slicers. The Tiny Lizard article was not trying to imply that you are somehow actually finding the model, just using the model to help you understand the query/filter context.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm afraid I don't exactly understand what you said @mmarie  Any chance you could rephrase it?  Tinylizard explicitly says: a) a slicer can apply a filter to a (lookup) table  b) any filters applied to a lookup table are also applied to related data tables  I am not seeing this behavior.

Comment: Nothing you do on an Excel spreadsheet actually filters the model. The only way to filter the model is to open the Power Pivot window and filter the table and save it. When Tinylizard says a slicer applies a filter to a table, it means within the scope of the query rather than literally applying a filter to the model. He's making this point to explain that relationships in Power Pivot are not bi-directional. Slicers, along with row headers and column headers in a pivot table provide [query context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413423(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: So slicers add context to your query. They filter the set of rows from the table returned by the query that is executed by the pivot table. Tiny Lizard isn't technically incorrect. You have just interpreted that article differently than intended.

Comment: But the point of contention is whether the slicer acts upon the entire model, or not.  I'm not seeing how it's a matter of interpretation - either the entire model is filtered by the slicer, or it is not.

Comment: Slicers only affect the pivot tables to which they are connected.

Comment: That's how it seems, meaning the article is technically incorrect, right?

Comment: The article is technically correct. What the query "sees" when looking at the model through the slicer, is the filtered structure resulting from the filter flowing through the directed relationships. The model is not filtered, the view of the (entire) model is.